# Function to get a list of all comments on 1 post

Tags: comments

I want to create a page where visitors can give a reference (ID) of a post and when they click on submit they get an overview of all given comments on that particular post.

I think I have to create a function behinde the submit button?

Thanks for helping me out. I'm farely new to Wordpress.

KR,
Kim

Comment: Why the user input? Who would know the post-ID?

Comment: Jekyll OP might have a drop-down of posts with titles and post-ID as option values..

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`get_comments( $args )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) and add the post ID in the arguments (`$args`) array:

```
$post_id = 1; // post ID here from the submitted data
$comments = get_comments(array( 'post_id' => (int) $post_id ));
// dump the comments found
print_r( $comments );
```

That would get you a comments list on that post. Hope that helps.